# understanding sed lines in csh script

Tags: sed, csh

I "inherited" an old csh script, which runs fine, but now i was asked to improve something. Now I try to understand what was programmed some years ago...

At some places sed was used to extract filenames or directory names and I am not able to understand in detal what happens there. Perhaps someome is able and kind to explain it to me.

The code lines are:

```
set File = `echo $Dirnames[$i] |sed 's/.*\///'`".bdf"
set Dir = `echo $Dirnames[$i] | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'`
```

I understand all the code except the sed parts...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/topics

Comment: also suggest to use `basename "$Dirnames[$i]"` and `dirname "$Dirnames[$i]"` if these commands are available

Comment: Is there any point re-iterating the common knowledge that you should not use csh to write scripts? [Google "csh why not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Dirname[$i]` is assigned a file path:

- `sed 's/.*\///'`: removes from path any characters up to last slash `.*\/`. The remaining part of the path (ie the file) is echoed with `.bdf` extension
- `s/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/`: outputs the path of the file directory. All characters up to last `/` are captured `\(.*\)` and output using backreference `\1`